# is there a way to disable touchpad scrolling in just a specific app (eg. Pantheon Terminal)?

Tags: settings, pantheon-terminal, touchpad, macbook, release-jolnir

I’m on Elementary OS 6.1 on an early 2015 MacBook Pro.

I’ve noticed the easiest way to disable trackpad scrolling is to change the scroll method from “Two Finger” to “Edge” in Settings. now, admittedly, “edge” scrolling doesn’t seem to work but it has the net effect of disabling scrolling:

[image: Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Touchpad]

Unfortunately, I later discovered it disables scrolling where it’s actually useful like in my web browser.

Is there a way to disable Trackpad scrolling for just a specific app, like Terminal?

I’ve poked around and read lots of posts here, in the Ubuntu stackexchange (like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130149/how-to-disable-horizontal-scrolling-in-ubuntu-18-04-in-terminal)), and random blog posts (like [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/enable-disable-touchpad-scrolling-tapping-command-line)) and all of them use the command line to disable scrolling entirely.

I’m happy to tinker around on the command line if it means I can restrict/scope disabling scrolling to specific apps.

I’m wondering if there is a construct for this we can leverage?